How can I automatically cancel slow downloads and automatically rerun them with the Internet Archive Python library?
I use the Python library internetarchive to download files from archive.org, e.g. to download https://archive.org/details/meetingbank-alameda I run:
pip install internetarchive
ia download meetingbank-alameda

I see that a few files download have a low download speeds (see red arrows) compared to others. If I kill and rerun ia download meetingbank-alameda, then the same files are typically fast to download: it's just that once in a while, a transfer is slow, and restarting the transfer typically makes it fast. How can I automatically cancel slow downloads and automatically rerun them?

